# " hadoop fs -ls " listing files in the present working directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am following the [Udacity's course](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud617/l-308873795/m-309508557) on Hadoop which instructs using the command `hadoop fs -ls` to list files. But on my machine running Ubuntu, it instead list files in the present working directory. What am I doing wrong?

`which hadoop` commands gives the output:
/home/usrname/hadoop-2.5.1//hadoop

Are the double slashes in the path the cause of this problem?

Comment: your files would be exactly same as hdfs?

Comment: @almasshaikh: I ruled out that possibility by trying the command from different directories.

Comment: Paste output of following commands: ls; hadoop fs -ls; alias hadoop; which hadoop

Comment: `ls` - list files in current directory; `hadoop fs -ls` same as ls. `alias hadoop` bash:alias: hadoop: not found; `which hadoop`/home/usrname/hadoop-2.5.1/bin//hadoop (suspect double slashes in the path might be a problem?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You file system must be pointing to local file system. Just modify the configuration to point it to HDFS and restart the processes.

Check this configuration:

```
 <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://<IP>:<Port></value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup path for hadoop root folder in your current users ***.bashrc file*** something as

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/seo/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
```

then add it to your system path variable as

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:
```

And then when you use

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

**will list your hdfs file system file if your hadoop cluster is up and running.**

Comment: Not getting any error. It just lists the files in the current working directory instead of listing the files in HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your client is not picking up the correct hadoop configuration files which is why it defaults to your local filesystem.

Set HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the directory of the hadoop configuration files. Also verify that fs.defaultFS is specified correctly in core-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try running the below command? Please do so after checking that the configuration suggested by Ashish is available in your core-site.xml.

hadoop dfs -ls hdfs://IP:PORT/

Thanks
Arani