# hadoop fs -ls results in "no such file or directory"

Tags: hadoop, uri, hdfs

I have installed and configured Hadoop 2.5.2 for a 10 node cluster. 1 is acting as masternode and other nodes as slavenodes.

I have problem in executing hadoop fs commands. hadoop fs -ls command is working fine with HDFS URI. It gives message "ls: `.': No such file or directory" when used without HDFS URI

```
ubuntu@101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls
15/01/30 17:03:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop 
ibrary for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `.': No such file or directory
ubuntu@101-master:~$
```

Whereas, executing the same command with HDFS URI

```
ubuntu@101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://101-master:50000/
15/01/30 17:14:31 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop      
library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - ubuntu supergroup          0 2015-01-28 12:07 hdfs://101-master:50000/hvision-data
-rw-r--r--   2 ubuntu supergroup   15512587 2015-01-28 11:50 hdfs://101-master:50000/testimage.seq
 drwxr-xr-x   - ubuntu supergroup          0 2015-01-30 17:03 hdfs://101-master:50000/wrodcount-in
 ubuntu@101-master:~$
```

I am getting exception in MapReduce program due to this behavior. jarlib is referring to the HDFS file location, whereas, I want jarlib to refer to the jar files stored at the local file system on the Hadoop nodes.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The behaviour that you are seeing is expected, let me explain what's going on when you are working with `hadoop fs` commands.

The command's syntax is this: `hadoop fs -ls [path]`

By default, when you don't specify `[path]` for the above command, hadoop expands the path to `/home/[username]` in hdfs; where `[username]` gets replaced with linux username who is executing the command.

So, when you execute this command:

```
ubuntu@xad101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls
```

the reason you are seeing the error is `ls: '.': No such file or directory` because hadoop is looking for this path `/home/ubuntu`, it seems like this path doesn't exist in hdfs.

The reason why this command:

```
ubuntu@101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://101-master:50000/
```

is working because, you have explicitly specified `[path]` and is the root of the hdfs. You can also do the same using this:

```
ubuntu@101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls /
```

which automatically gets evaluated to the root of hdfs.

Hope, this clears the behaviour you are seeing while executing `hadoop fs -ls` command.

Hence, if you want to specify local file system path use `file:///` url scheme.

Comment: maybe default path is ` /user/[username]` now.

Answer (score 20):

this has to do with the missing home directory for the user. Once I created the home directory under the hdfs for the logged in user, it worked like a charm..

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user

hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/{loggedin user}

hdfs dfs -ls
```

this method fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

The user directory in Hadoop is (in HDFS)

```
/user/<your operational system user>
```

If you get this error message it may be because you have not yet created your user directory within HDFS.

Use

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/<current o.p. user directory>
```

To see what is your current operational system user, use:

```
id -un
```

`hadoop fs -ls` it should start working...

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things at work here; based on "jarlib is referring to the HDFS file location", it sounds like you indeed have an HDFS path set as your `fs.default.name`, which is indeed the typical setup. So, when you type `hadoop fs -ls`, this is indeed trying to look inside HDFS, except it's looking in your [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684746/hadoop-fs-ls-listing-files-in-the-present-working-directory), which should be something like `hdfs://101-master:50000/user/ubuntu`. The error message is unfortunately somewhat confusing since it doesn't tell you that `.` was interpreted to be that full path. If you `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/ubuntu` then `hadoop fs -ls` should start working.

This problem is unrelated to your "jarlib" problem; whenever you want to refer files explicitly stored in the local filesystem, but where the path goes through Hadoop's `Path` resolution, you simply need to add `file:///` to force Hadoop to refer to the local filesystem. For example:

```
hadoop fs -ls file:///tmp
```

Try passing your jar file paths as fille `file:///path/to/your/jarfile` and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your 
platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

This error will be removed using this command in .bashrc file:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"

------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/hadoop is location where hadoop is install
-------------------------------------------------------
```