# missing /user directory in hadoop-2.7.2

Tags: hadoop2

I am bit new to hadoop. I have recently install a stable version of Apache Hadoop 2.7.2 on ubuntu 14.04 OS.

I am trying to execute some basic Hadoop command such as follow

```
hadoop version
```

The command gives me the correct output as follows that is correct.

[image]
However, when I try to execute the `hadoop fs -ls`, it give me error.

[image]

I have searched the previous question related to this problem on stackoverflow such as [StackoverflowQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241251/hadoop-fs-ls-results-in-no-such-file-or-directory). But, I am not finding `/user` directory in my hadoop installation. Could you please help me how can I resolve this issue?

The content of my `.bashrc` file is as follows:
[image]

The content of `hdfs-site.xml` file is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Posibilly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241251/hadoop-fs-ls-results-in-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

First of all the command "hadoop fs -ls" is a command to the HDFS file system and not a Linux command.

Second, the command as you typed it is incomplete. The correct syntax is "hadoop fs -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] " where the [-d], [-h] and [-R] components of the command are optional. That said, you MUST specify a path for the "args" component. The "args" component of the command expects an HDFS path (e.g. substituting / for "args" will list the entire tree ** ON HDFS ** starting at the HDFS root directory /). You will need to create a directory called "user" on HDFS under the root directory using "hadoop fs -mkdir /user". The the command "hadoop fs -ls /user" will work and will show an empty user directory.

Third, there is no way to tell HDFS to use a value for the "args" by supplying it a value of a local filesystem (Linux) path ...which is what you are attempting or understanding it to be. Any value for "args" must resolve to an HDFS filesystem path and not a Linux filesystem path.

Fourth, for newcomers to Hadoop, it is very important to have a clear distinction between the native host operating system filesystem  (in this case Linux filesystem) and the Hadoop filesystem (in this case HDFS).

Answer (score 0):

one thing to note when doing a hadoop commands in v2.7.2 is that, hadoop works **on top of** Linux OS, hence when we want to access into Hadoop Distributed File System, we would use something like this command; `hdfs dfs -ls /` instead of hadoop fs -ls.

Also, in your hdfs-site.xml configurations, you seemed to miss out adding this properties.

```
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.dir</name>
<value>file://path/to/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Please take note of your $HADOOP_HOME as well.